# MS Access trying to set ADODB recordset to return from com object

Tags: vba, ms-access, comobject, comaddin

I have written a Shared Add In using VS 2008 which contains a public method that returns an ADO Recordset. In MS Access I would like to set a ADO Recordset to the return of the function call. The function call executes fine when calling the COM object. However assigning a ADO Recordset in VBA to the function returns a "Compile error: Invalid use of Property" . What am I doing wrong?

```
Dim result As ADODB.Recordset

result = .Object.doSomething(parameter1, parameter2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `Set` keyword when assigning to an object variable.

```
Dim result As ADODB.Recordset

Set result = .Object.doSomething(parameter1, parameter2)
```

Comment: Thanks Hansup, I rarely ever work in vba and have little experience in the syntax. Your suggestion worked!